# Which api is used to get username of authenticated user via oauth in php?

Tags: php, oauth

I had perform google authentication in my web portal done in php.
now i want to access the name and the email address of the authenticated user, so which api is used to achieve this?
Code:

```
<?php

    // put your code here
    require_once 'app/init.php';

    $googleClient = new \Google_Client();
    $auth = new \GoogleAuth($googleClient);

    if ($auth->checkRedirectCode()) {
        header('Location : index.php');
    }

?>

<?php if (!$auth->isLoggedIn()): ?>
    <h2>Login to your account</h2>

    <a href="<?php echo $auth->getAuthUrl(); ?>"><img src="img/gbtn.png"></a>
    <hr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You get it like this:

```
$user = $client->getAuthService()->userinfo->get();
                        $user_id = $user['id'];
                        $user_name = filter_var($user['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
                        $email = filter_var($user['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
                        $profile_url = filter_var($user['link'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
                        $profile_image_url    = filter_var($user['picture'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
```